# Counting Rows Includes JSON by Id in Codeigniter

Tags: php, sql, json, ajax, codeigniter

1. We have one groups table name as "groups" (There is mail groups)
2. We have one person table name as "person" (There is persons who has
   in mail groups)

We saved person in the "person" table with json_encode by group ID. Because a person can belong to more than one group.

[image]

The problem is we can not get count rows of "person" table by groups.
We want to get some information like X Mail Group Has 10 People, Y Mail Group Has 5 People, etc.
We should get this information with id by counting the json encoded sql rows. But how? We need help with these issues.

Our Code;

```
$jsonGroups = $this->db->get("person")->result();

foreach ($jsonGroups as $jsGro) {

    $jsGro->personEmailGroup = json_decode($jsGro->personEmailGroup);

    if(in_array($group->mailGroupId, $jsGro->personEmailGroup)) {

        $this->db->select('*');
        $query = $this->db->where('personId', $jsGro->personId)->where('personStatus', 1)->get('person');
        $num = $query->num_rows();
        if($num>0) {
            echo '&nbsp;' .$num;
        } else {

        }
    }
}
```

With the above code, the result is nothing.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you read that? Or do you think it would be a good idea to format that so we at least can

Comment: If its not to late, refactor your database to use proper normal form and then these queries will be soooooo much easier. I would suggest a a link table containing `person_id, group_id` and there you have a proper relational database design. This would also make creating the links between person and group a whole lot easier

Comment: I just want to get working code. Above code doesn't work about counting rows.

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: I know, but I just want to do that with json. In person table, there will be much more information and working with json much better i think.

Comment: I cannot see a single good reason for JSON in a relational database, and look at the problems it is causing you now

Comment: Sorry but I do not know what version of MySQL. But I think it is not old version.

Comment: Google `how to show mysql version` it makes a difference to the query syntax that is available for digging around in a mess of json

Comment: I think, without JSON, I should use at least 3 tables for relational database. But I can use at least 2 tables if I use JSON. So in person table there may be 10000+ people in same table. But may be you should tell me another ways for this issue, thank you.

Comment: The server is not under my control right now, but I'll look into it. I use real server, not local server.

Comment: Ok so you are using one less table. Great. But now querying the data is much harder! Where do you see the benefit in that statement.

Comment: Yes it is hard, but so I wanted to get help for this. Harder but not impossible I think.

Comment: So you have some research to do in the MySQL Manual

Comment: I have searched about it but I can not found any information.

Comment: Anyone can solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this kind of design with json for relations is not optimal but is your choice.

Assuming your sql server has support for JSON functions and you are using codeigniter 3, here is a sample way to get the number of members using the [JSON_CONTAINS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html) function

```
$sub_query = $this->db
                ->select('groups.groupsId,COUNT(*) AS NumberOfPerson')
                ->join('person',"JSON_CONTAINS(person.personEmailGroup, CONCAT('\"',groups.groupsId,'\"'), '$')")
                ->group_by('groupsId')
                ->from('groups')
                ->get_compiled_select();

$allGroups = $this->db
                    ->select('groups.*, personcounter.NumberOfPerson')
                    ->join("($sub_query) personcounter", "personcounter.groupsId= groups.groupsId","left")
                    ->from('groups')
                    ->get()
                    ->result();
echo '<pre>';
print_r($allGroups );
echo '</pre>';
```

I recommand to use pagination insead to get all groups.

Another option, without JSON_CONTAINS  function is to check the group membership of each user and count them. For big `person` table use query with limit and offset till all table is scanned - please take a look on codeigniter  documentation [Limiting Results](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#limiting-or-counting-results)

```
// this are all users - not recomended due to memory leak
$users = $this->db->get("person")->result();
// array with group_id as key and group members as value
// will contains only groups with members
$groups_counter = array();
foreach ($users as $user) {
    $user_groups = json_decode($user->personEmailGroup);
    foreach($user_groups as $groupId){
        if(!isset($groups_counter [$groupId])){
            $groups_counter [$groupId] = 1;
        } else {
            $groups_counter[$groupId] += 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Best regards